# set a default label at my node on Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I am new at Neo4J and I am creating a graph. My nodes does not show the property I want as default on my graph.

```
CREATE (Bakuman:Manga {titulo:'Bakuman', tituloOriginal: 'Bakuman', capitulos:'176',volumes:'20', dataPublicacao:'8 de Agosto de 2008 a 23 de Abril de 2012',status:'Completo'}),
(AttackOnTitan:Manga {titulo:'AttackOnTitan', tituloOriginal: 'AttackOnTitan', capitulos:'unknown',volumes:'unknown', dataPublicacao:'9 de Setembro de 2008',status:'Em Publicação'})
RETURN Bakuman,AttackOnTitan
```

My node shows 176 instead of Bakuman.

Comment: see also: http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See attached screen shot on how to change the default caption.

[image: neo4j browser node label]